# SQLite Query creation

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want the the KEYWORD column should contain the unique value  in SQLite database. How can I modify following query to do so?

Query is as follows:

```
  String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_WORD + " TEXT "
            + KEY_KEYCODE + " TEXT" + ")";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UNIQUE` modifier.

```
String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_WORD + " TEXT UNIQUE "
            + KEY_KEYCODE + " TEXT" + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the UNIQUE keyword:

```
String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_WORD + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
        + KEY_KEYCODE + " TEXT" + ")";
```